# "mvn install" witk skipped the artifacts folder

Tags: maven, primefaces

I have got simple java project:

```
  <groupId>pl.cichon.andrzej.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jfaces-theme</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

With structure in src folder like this:

[image: Project structure]

How to generate simple jar, with content just like my structure? When i run "mvn install", it creates jar with src folder "pl.cichon.andrzej.primefaces.jfaces-theme" with no content inside. I want to simple jar with the structure like my src content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioning at [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Put those files under the `src/main/resources`. e.g.

```
src
`--main
   `--resources
      `--META-INF
         `--resources
            `--primefaces-jfaces
               |--images
                `--themes.css
```

The `mvn clean install` will put those files in a form of the structure that you need.